# Oracle BI Answers - Replace Null with Value in another Column

Tags: oracle, isnull

I'm creating a query in Oracle BI Answers. I am checking for a value which may return as Null from (let's say) C1. If null is returned, I wish to check for a value in a different column (C2) and use that.

Can anybody let me know how I would do that.

I am guessing I will check for Null using an If statement and if that returns true, I will check C2 for a value and use that but I don't quite know how to do that.

MC

I know I can hardcode a value if null is returned, however, I cannot see how I will return a value from another field.

Comment: I don't know *Oracle BI Answers*, but - as it is Oracle, maybe it'll help: in pure SQL, that would be `nvl(c1, c2)`. If it were Forms, items are preceded by colons so it would then be `nvl(:c1, :c2)`.

Comment: I have no experience with [Oracle BI Answers](https://www.bitool.net/software/bi-answers.html) but I gather that you can enter SQL queries. In [Oracle] SQL there is no `if`. There is `case` expression or `coalesce()` function.